# wpf c# status window update

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I am trying to create a status window which content(textbox) should change in a lengthy operation. 
This status window is called and updated from the main application.
Unfortunately, the content is updated only at the finish of the operation.
I am using VS2008, C# and WPF.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in another answer to allow better formatting:

The code should like pretty much like this:

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);

bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new 
    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

In the `bgWorker_DoWork` method, call "`Dispatcher.Invoke`" (or "`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`", depends on the circumstances) and the delegate for the invoke may update your textbox (because it's in the same thread as the textbox).

Comment: BackgroundWorker already supports progress updating (via BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged).  Why would you want to add another level of indirection with Dispatcher Invoke/BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a service and the call is synchronous, the main application does not get any chance to update. You need to put them on a different thread. Also, if the service call is getting a higher priority (UI threads are always of less priority), you need to forcibly tell the system to update these.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the lengthy operation in a BackgroundWorker thread and notifying the content every once in a while by using the Dispatcher? It will give a responsive yet progressive feeling to your UI.

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how to do this?